# Android - EditText saves T9 suggested values

Tags: android, android-edittext

I have an application where user inputs text into EditText field. After user clicks OK (in keyboard input mode), a correct value is in the EditText (lets say "Smile").

```
if (answers.get(counter).getText().equals(opponentAnswers.get(counter)))
```

But this if statement fails, because the same EditText has the values that were suggested by T9 option, when user was inputing his answer (for example values of EditText would be "Smile Smiling Smiled"), while it should only have a value "Smile".

Any ideas how to solve this issue?

Comment: You can turn predictive text off: `myEditText.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_NO_SUGGESTIONS);`

Comment: That didn't help, T9 was still on. Even weirder, I realized, it trim off the first letter of primary suggested word and saves it as a value. Then Any other suggested word is just added to the value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's really weird. These are kind of guesses, but this is what I'd try next if I were you:

A. Instead of doing an equals against getText(), try doing a toString on getText(), so:

`if (answers.get(counter).getText().toString().equals(opponentAnswers.get(counter)))`

B. If that doesn't work then you could try adding a TextWatcher using `addTextChangedListener` on the EditText, and getting the value from that. Calling toString() on the editable returned in afterTextChanged might give you the value you want.

```
private class SearchTextWatcher implements TextWatcher {

    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
            int after) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
            int count) {
    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
         //Get the text the user sees
         String textShownToUser = s.toString();
    }

}
```

Hope this helps! Best of luck!

Comment: Well, "toString()" really helped, if statement returned true. Even tough, in a debugger EditText's mText(SpannableStringBuilder) had value 'Smile', but in its sub branch mText(id=123..) had suggested values. Thank you!